# Unity - LineRenderer doesn't appear on build (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created the following script to draw a circle:

```
    int numSegments = 128; // The number of line segments we are going to draw.
    float circleWidth = 0.15f;

    GameObject myGameObject= new GameObject("Circle");
    myGameObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
    myGameObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    myGameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f);

    LineRenderer lineRenderer = myGameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Mobile/Particles/Additive"));
    lineRenderer.SetColors(Color.blue, Color.blue);
    lineRenderer.SetWidth(circleWidth, circleWidth);
    lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(numSegments + 1);
    lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = false;

    float deltaTheta = (float)(2.0 * Mathf.PI) / numSegments;
    float theta = 0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < numSegments + 1; i++)
    {
        float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(theta);
        float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(theta);
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, 1f);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, pos);
        theta += deltaTheta;
    }
```

While it works fine in Unity (with the Guizmos off), once it is built, the circle doesn't appear.
I am actually a little confuse why it is the case.

**EDIT**: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: shader --> So it would seem that isn't included

I guess I need to include it somehow ?

Comment: Maybe an exception occured, and your code ain't even reaching to this part, did you verified this is not the case with development build/logs?

Comment: It seems that "Mobile/Particles/Additive" isn't included in the build.

Comment: Whats your target device ? Looks like the shader is not supported, make a build with a simple shader

Comment: Windows and Android. It works once I have included it in the Project Settings. However I don't know how to get the Unity Mobile/Particles/Additive (to add it in the project settings). I guess it must be somewhere otherwise the local build wouldn't work

Comment: Have you tried adding the shader to the `Always Included Shaders` in `Edit > Project Settings > Graphics`?

Comment: Indeed it fixes it if I add a random custom Shader, but I would like to add the unity :"Mobile/Particles/Additive" one but I don't know how to get it

Comment: @Scipion if you increase the size of the `Always Included Shaders` array, tap on the little circle of the new element, and search for an "additive" shader, you will find `Mobile/Particles/Additive`.

Comment: Thank you, it was incredibly easy and I should have found it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Iggy's comment:

if you increase the size of the Always Included Shaders array, tap on the little circle of the new element, and search for an "additive" shader, you will find Mobile/Particles/Additive.