# LineRenderer build issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-webgl

I have a line renderer lightning effect in my game, which works perfectly in Unity but unfortunately isn't working when I export the build. I have tried in both WebGL and Windows with the same [null] result.

I have followed the advice in other questions dating back to 2014, including creating a custom material and adding it to the Resources folder; referencing it in the script/Inspector; changing graphics settings; sorting layer etc. to no avail.

Here's the relevant method:

```
private void ShootLightning(GameObject asteroid)
    {
        GameObject lightning = Instantiate(lightningEffect, LightningSpawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

        Vector3 start = LightningSpawnPoint.position;
        Vector3 end = asteroid.transform.position;
        var points = CreateLightning(start, end, displacementFactor);

        LineRenderer lineRenderer = lightning.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Count;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(points.ToArray());

        Material lineMaterial = Resources.Load<Material>("LightningMaterial");
        lineRenderer.material = lineMaterial;

        Destroy(lightning, 0.1f);
    }
```

Is there anything else I should be trying?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - LineRenderer doesn't appear on build (2D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59529261/unity-linerenderer-doesnt-appear-on-build-2d)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The LightningMaterial I created uses the Legacy Shaders/Particles/Additive shader, which I thought would ensure Unity included it in the build.